# android inflater

Tags: android, locale, layout-inflater

Is there any way to notify: when the inflater service inflates a view?
I want to get every generated view and make some changes, to support some locales and languages that is not natively supported by android before 2.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LayoutInflater.Factory` may help you. Here you can find a good example how to use it http://sergiandreplace.com/blog/2012/11/15/dealing-with-fonts-and-inflaters-in-android/